# 'dyld: Library not loaded' error inside iOS framework

Tags: ios, frameworks

**The problem**

I have build an iOS framework which uses a 3rd party framework. When I try to use the framework inside an iOS app, the following error comes up noticing me that the 3rd party framework I used couldn't be loaded.

> dyld: Library not loaded

If I copy the 3rd party framework into the iOS app, everything will work smoothly. Is there a solution out there that would allow me use a 3rd party library without the necessity to copy again the framework inside the iOS app?

**Things that I have tried:**

1. Creating a 'copy phase' inside the iOS framework with the destination 'Frameworks'. It will not work.

Comment: If you don't include the 3rd-party framework in the app the how is the app supposed to access it?

Comment: I was thinking I could pack it inside the framework I build, like you can do with the resources.

Comment: You will need to copy the framework into the app bundle during the build.  You will probably need to use `install_name_tool` in order to ensure the frameworks are referenced correctly at runtime.  This is best done by setting the *run path* to `@loader_path` or `@loader_path/Frameworks` (depending on how you are laying out the app bundle) and setting the "install name" as `@rpath/Name.framework`.  This will need doing to both your framework (from the executable) and to the 3rd-party framework (from your framework).

Comment: Will have a look into that and will come back with an answer. Thank you!